# Vaadin problem in Spring Boot multi module project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, vaadin

I made up an example spring boot project running with Vaadin (latest version). I only have one view:

```
@Route
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
```

The UI was working like a charm, then I had to refactor the project in modules.
I put the SpringBootApplication in a module and Vaadin in another one. I'm getting into modules, so I don't know exactly how they interact, but I had to put the dependency in the boot pom to the vaadin pom in order to let it start.
Now it is not working, when I call localhost it says

> Could not navigate to ''
>
> Reason: Couldn't find route for ''
>
> Available routes:
>
> This detailed message is only shown when running in
>   development mode.

The spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.app"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"my.app"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"my.app"})
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class LicensemanagerApplication
```

boot module pom.xml dependency snippet:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>app_frontend</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

app_frontend module pom.xml dependency snippet:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
     <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 </dependency>
.............
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vaadin by default only looks for `@Route` annotated classes within the same package that contains the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. To make it look in other packages, you need to pass those as the value to the `@EnableVaadin` annotation, e.g. `@EnableVaadin({"my.app"})`.